# Issue with Caesar cypher project

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

I'm making a Caesar cypher project in Python for my school assignment, I've done the base but I'm confused on how to move one letter forward. Recommend any methods?

```
def encrypt(word):
    # Somehow move one letter forward.

secret_word = encrypt(input("Enter word: "))
print(secret_word)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something in Python called `ord` to get the integer value and add that by one.
Here is the solution:

```
def encrypt(word):
    encrypted = ""
    for letter in word:
        encrypted += chr(ord(letter) + 1)

    return encrypted
```

And if you want to the inverse of `ord`, then you can use `chr`.
This would be the decrypt function:

```
def decrypt(word):
    decrypted = ""
    for letter in word:
        decrypted += chr(ord(letter) - 1)

    return decrypted
```

FYI, when a letter like "a" is used inside the `ord` function, it returns `97`, and if we were to use the decrypt method on "a", then it would return " ` " which is not useful, but you can add a simple `if` statement which fixes this issue.

Comment: And it should be noted `chr()` is the inverse of `ord()`; it takes a codepoint, as returned by `ord()`, and turns it into a string.